# How to execute or load servlet in div?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

Hi I am trying to open a div on `<a>` tag hover, that completes.
I want to to load jsp page data in that div.
But the problem is that jsp page data comes from servlet, so un till servlet not executes the data will not come to jsp page.

my servlet name is `showcart.java`.
the page that receive data from `showcart.java` is `vcart.jsp`.

I have tried `<jsp:include page="vcart.jsp"></jsp:include>` but page data is empty.
So i want some mechanism so that servlet executes and then it pass control and data to `vcart.jsp`.

My code :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Reading Image</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .testtmpblock{
            display: none;
            background-color: black;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            color: white;
        }

    </style>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
      $(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {
          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").show();
      }).on('mouseleave', '.cart', function () {
          $(this).next(".testtmpblock").hide();
      });
  });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="cart"> Cart </a>

    <div class="testtmpblock">
    <jsp:include page="vcart.jsp"></jsp:include>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me that how to load sevlet in div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use here ajax to load data from servlet on mouse enter.
In `mouseenter` function, you can write this code:

```
$.ajax(
{
  url:'showcart.jsp,'//Or whatever name is 
  type:'get',
  success:function(response)
  {
     $('.testtmpblock').html(response);
  }
});
```

It will load that servlet's html rendered code into your div.

Comment: in mouseenter function means  `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.cart', function () {` in this ? and I have tried it but it shows me an error at line `url:'showcart.jsp,'`. will you exact tell me the place ?

Comment: @Aniket : it's too awesome.. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than including a JSP, make an ajax call to your Servlet to get the data and display it in the div it self.

```
$("button").click(function(){   //replace this with your event
  $.ajax({url:"showcart",success:function(result){
    $("#testtmpblock").html(result);
  }});
});
```

Comment: I have tried it with exact code but still it doesn't show the data. I have put button also `<input type="button" value="Hit">`.

Comment: Please share your Servlet code. When a ajax request comes in your servlet should return the  data to it .  I prefer JSON format which need to parsed in above jquery script. What i posted above was more like a syntax.

Comment: Ok sir but above answer gave me the solution. It's work tremendous and so dynamic.